# How to open only Google Drive with SAF or without SAF?

Tags: java, android

I have following code to open the storage access framework:

```
private void startDialog()
    {
        Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData)
    {        
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);
    }
```

But in in the SAF, I can select all places on my device. How can I open directly only my Google Drive Account? One way maybe is of the SAF and another way is over the google drive rest api v3. I can authenticate me with them, but i don't know how to open files with the api. With api v2 i could open file via: `Drive.DriveApi` but the `DriveApi` is deprecated.

Comment: "But in in the SAF, I can select all places on my device" -- why not allow the user to open a document from wherever the user wants? Why is it in the user's interest for them to be restricted?

Comment: The app should directly open the drive storage because i wan't not select between my many google accounts. Is this possible?

Comment: Not through the Storage Access Framework, unless you previously opened the document tree for Google Drive (via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`) and use that as a starting location. Even then, the user could navigate elsewhere in the SAF UI and pick a document from a different provider.

Comment: OK, but can i open the drive storage though the `googel rest api v3`

Comment: I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: I found nothing android doc for the api. E.g. how can I sync a file with the drive storage with the new api?